# EclipseLink (JPA) two @OneToMany for the same entity?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, one-to-many

I have four models:

```
    Public class Product {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "product_id")
        private Long productId;

        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "product", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
        private List<Director> directorList;

        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "product", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
        private List<Actor> actorList;
    }
    public class Actor {

        @MapsId("peopleId")
        @JoinColumn(name = "people_id", referencedColumnName = "PEOPLE_ID", insertable = true, updatable = true)
        @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private People people;

        @MapsId("productId")
        @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "product_id", insertable = true, updatable = true)
        @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private Product product;
    }
    public class Director {
        @MapsId("peopleId")
        @JoinColumn(name = "people_id", referencedColumnName = "PEOPLE_ID", insertable = true, updatable = true)
        @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private People people;

        @MapsId("productId")
        @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "product_id", insertable = true, updatable = true)
        @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private Product product;
    }
    public class People {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "PEOPLE_ID")
        private Long peopleId;
        private String name;
        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "people", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private List<Director> directorList;

        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "people", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private List<Actor> actorList;
    }
```

My problem here is when i save the product with  two Lists, both of them contain the same people name and the result is i have two insert in people :

```
    Product product = new Product();

    People people = new People();
    people.setName("John");

    Director director = new Director();
    director.setPeople(people);
    product.getDirectorList().add(director);

    Actor actor = new Actor();
    actor.setPeople(people);
    product.getActorList().add(actor);

    dao.update(p);
```

I have tested change equals and hashcode of people entity to avoid duplication but does not work ?

Comment: you have to persist people first and then add the managed object to lists

Comment: i can't call any persist other than product persist because the object contains other relation.

Comment: Have you tried this? Certainly you can persist an object without any relation. The process will be: persist people -> persist director and actor with persisted people -> update people with persisted director and actor

Comment: no not work always tow rows

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, don't understand the sentence: **no not work always tow rows**

Secondly, why do you need @MapsId?

Thirdly, why do you need fetchType= FetchType.Lazy in @OneToMany, because it is default behavior?

Finnaly, i tried and it works. Of course have to change the order because you have optional=false in some relations.

```
    People people = new People();
    people.setName("John");
    entityManager.persist(people); --> Create people

    Product product = new Product();
    entityManager.persist(product); --> Create product

    Director director = new Director();
    director.setPeople(people);
    director.setProduct(product);
    entityManager.persist(director); --> Create director

    Actor actor = new Actor();
    actor.setPeople(people);
    actor.setProduct(product);
    entityManager.persist(actor);  --> Create actor


    product.getDirectorList().add(director);
    product.getActorList().add(actor);
    entityManager.merge(product); --> update product

    people.getActorList().add(actor);
    people.getDirectorList().add(director);

    entityManager.merge(people);  --> update people
```

**Result:**

People

```
1   John
```

Actor

```
ID   PEOPLE_ID    PRODUCT_ID
4    1            2
```

Director

```
ID   PEOPLE_ID    PRODUCT_ID
3    1            2
```

Product

```
ID
2
```

**Updated**

ABaseEntity

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class ABaseEntity {

private int id;

public ABaseEntity(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public ABaseEntity() {
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

Director

```
@Entity
public class Director extends ABaseEntity{

private People people;

private Product product;

@JoinColumn(name = "people_id", referencedColumnName = "ID")
@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
public People getPeople() {
    return people;
}

public void setPeople(People people) {
    this.people = people;
}

@JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "ID")
@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
public Product getProduct() {
    return product;
}

public void setProduct(Product product) {
    this.product = product;
}
}
```

People

```
@Entity
public class People extends ABaseEntity {

private String name;
private List<Director> directorList = new ArrayList<>();


private List<Actor> actorList = new ArrayList<>();

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "people")
public List<Director> getDirectorList() {
    return directorList;
}

public void setDirectorList(List<Director> directorList) {
    this.directorList = directorList;
}

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "people")
public List<Actor> getActorList() {
    return actorList;
}

public void setActorList(List<Actor> actorList) {
    this.actorList = actorList;
}
}
```

Product

```
public class Product extends ABaseEntity{
private List<Director> directorList = new ArrayList<>();

private List<Actor> actorList = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "product", orphanRemoval = true)
public List<Director> getDirectorList() {
    return directorList;
}

public void setDirectorList(List<Director> directorList) {
    this.directorList = directorList;
}

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "product", orphanRemoval = true)
public List<Actor> getActorList() {
    return actorList;
}

public void setActorList(List<Actor> actorList) {
    this.actorList = actorList;
}
}
```

Comment: thank you for your time but the problem here you have 6 transaction to the database, what i need is in one transaction :entityManager.merge(product); do all what you do here? it is possible to merge all entity in cascade ?

Comment: Actually here is 1 transaction, 6 method calls, and jpa will execute 4 queries to the database. The number of transactions does not depend on how many times you invoke the method on entityManager. Regardings your question, i think that you cannot complete the task with just one method call to entityManager. But we can think together.

Comment: The problem is other entities must know, who is the person they are pointing to. With your initialization, you don't even know who exactly this person is (In relational database design point of view), because 'name' is not the primary  key of Person. That's why the framework will create two different people with the same name on your database.

Comment: i forget i use @MapsId to save in cascade and fetchType= FetchType.Lazy is netbeans generator entities

Comment: Actually you don't need those. Try to delete and see if your function still works.

Comment: Take a look at [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapsId.html) first. Of course, I already deleted all of your redundant configuration and it works.

Comment: if i delete mapid i get this error: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'product_id' cannot be null
Error Code: 1048
Call: INSERT INTO actor (sort_order, product_id, people_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
 bind => [1, null, null]

Answer (score 0):

the solution i found is like thanh ngo suggest so my methode save is like this :

```
Product product = new Product();

People people = new People();
people.setName("John");
dao.persist(people);

Director director = new Director();
director.setPeople(people);
product.getDirectorList().add(director);

Actor actor = new Actor();
actor.setPeople(people);
product.getActorList().add(actor);

dao.update(p);
```